# Custom payment method after payment user is logged out on thank you page

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

I am using a custom payment method called euplatesc for donations.

The form:

```
$postid = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), '_donar_post_id', true);
    $dataAll = array(
        //'amount'      => number_format(get_post_meta($postid, '_letter_price', true)),
        'amount'      => number_format(1),
        'curr'        => 'RON',
        'invoice_id'  => '',
        'order_desc'  => 'full payment',
        'merch_id'    => $providedbypaymentgeteway,                                                
        'timestamp'   => gmdate("YmdHis"),                                     
        'nonce'       => md5(microtime() . mt_rand()),       
    );
    
    
    
    $dataAll['fp_hash'] = strtoupper(euplatesc_mac($dataAll,$key));
    $dataAll['ExtraData[silenturl]'] = get_site_url();
    $dataAll['ExtraData[successurl]'] = get_site_url().'/thank-you';
    $dataAll['ExtraData[failedurl]'] = get_site_url().'/payment-error';
    $dataAll['ExtraData[backtosite]']= get_site_url();
    //$dataAll = array_merge($dataAll,$main);
    $dataAll['fname'] = get_post_meta($postid, '_fname', true);
    $dataAll['lname'] = get_post_meta($postid, '_lname', true);
    $dataAll['email'] = get_post_meta($postid, '_email', true);
    $dataAll['ExtraData[version]'] = 'donate';
    $main = "https://secure.euplatesc.ro";

    $ret.= '<form id="pay_full_amount_form" ACTION="'.$main.'" METHOD="POST" name="gateway" target="_self">';
    $ret.= '<input type="hidden" name="fullamount" VALUE="1" />';
    foreach($dataAll as $key=>$value){
        $ret.= '<input type="hidden" name="'.$key.'" VALUE="'.$value.'" />';
    }
    $ret .= '<input type="submit" value="'.__( 'Full ammount', 'gd-povestea-mea' ).'" name="wp-submit"/>';
    $ret.= '</form>';
    
    return $ret;
```

The payment works but after payment redirect on the thank you page the user is logged out.

The response field:

```
$key = '1234567890';
    
$data =  array (
    'amount'     => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['amount'])),
    'curr'       => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['curr'])), 
    'invoice_id' => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['invoice_id'])),
    'ep_id'      => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['ep_id'])), 
    'merch_id'   => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['merch_id'])), 
    'action'     => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['action'])), 
    'message'    => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['message'])),
    'approval'   => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['approval'])),
    'timestamp'  => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['timestamp'])),
    'nonce'      => addslashes(trim(@$_POST['nonce'])),
);

$data['fp_hash'] = strtoupper(euplatesc_mac($data, $key));
$fp_hash=addslashes(trim(@$_POST['fp_hash']));

if($data['fp_hash']===$fp_hash){
    if($data['action']=="0") {
        //Complete
    }else {
        //Failed
    }
}else{
    //Invalid
}

echo "OK";//IMPORTANT to print OK
```

Data is captured in the database but I need to show the user details that I cant cause the user is signed out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, if payment is successful generate unique key and set it in user browser (as cookie) and store same key in db. Then on thank you page you can show results based on that key.

This [tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-set-get-and-delete-wordpress-cookies-like-a-pro/) might help you if you didn't use cookies before.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).